# Upgrade Openx 2.8.10 to Revive Adserver 3.0.0 - how

Tags: openx

I've got some old OpenX installation to maintain and I have to upgrade it to some new version. I downloaded Revive sources, extracted it into some other directory, copied (and renamed) config file so that the installer knows it should proceed with upgrade instead of setting fresh installation. So far so good... However though on configuration step when I fill the `Path to previous Revive Adserver installation` field and click next I get an error saying that `One or more plugin files couln't be located, check the install.log file for more information`.

The mentioned log is quite huge (about 30kB) but in general there are two kinds of messages (domain is ofcourse different):

```
Plugin: openXMarket - Unable to locate XML files
Plugin: openXDeliveryLimitations - Unable to locate file: /home/takefam/public_html/_ads.example.com/extensions/deliveryLimitations/Client/Browser.class.php
```

The strange thing is that none of versions (existing OpenX 2.8.10, fresh OpenX 2.8.11 and fresh Revive Adserver 3.0.0) does not contain directory named `extensions`. Did you have such problem?

Also, I found that fresh Revive instalation goes without errors so I could just reinstall it but then I would have to migrate whole database - do you know any sensible scripts for that?

Answer (score 2):

Do not install from a zip of Github sources. They explicitly mentioned:

> Revive Adserver as available from github as a zip file is not suitable for
> installation on a server. It contains a number of files that are for
> development only, and are removed during the release packaging process.
>
> Please ONLY download Revive Adserver as a release package from the
> Revive Adserver website at http://www.revive-adserver.com/.

If you got the release package, follow these instructions:
http://blog.sucuri.net/upgrading-openx-quick-guide

Good luck.

Comment: I did use version from their site instead (actually I also tried with version from Github as well). Also I actually followed the steps described but did not work for me. Anyway I managed to set up fresh instalation and migrate whole data... Upgrade simply failed.

Answer (score 2):

1.Backup Openx Source Ad Server :

```
openx-2.8.X/www/images/*
openx-2.8.X/var/YourDomainName.conf.php
```

2.Install Revive Ad Server :

[Download Revive Ad Server](http://www.revive-adserver.com/releases/revive-adserver-3.0.0.zip)

Create a another new database

```
run revive-adserver-3.0.0/www/admin/install.php
```

3.Database Config :

```
Edit revive-adserver-3.0.0/var/YourDomainName.conf.php
```

change the revive ad server [database] details to OpenX Source database

4.Move Images :

```
Copy/Move Images from openx-2.8.X/www/images/* to revive-adserver-3.0.0/www/images/*
```

Regards,

Chinnu.G

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the full path of previous installation, not the one relative to web server root.
If you are not sure of what is the path, just create a file test.php into previous installation folder with this content:

```
<?php echo __DIR__; ?>
```

And open it in the browser. It will show the path to use.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced exactly the same issue. The problem was related to a manual security 'fix' applied to a previous version.

OpenX users had been advised in the past to fix a security vulnerability by upgrading or deleting a specific file included as part of the Video Ads Plugin:-

```
If you recently upgraded to version 2.8.6, you can simply install an 
upgraded video ad plug-in available [here] or remove the following file: 
/www/admin/plugins/videoReport/lib/ofc2/ofc_upload_image.php
from your installation.
```

Deleting the file resolved the security issue but broke the upgrade process.

To get the upgrade through I simply created an empty version of the missing file, i.e. create a blank 'ofc_upload_image.php' file in the '/www/admin/plugins/videoReport/lib/ofc2/' folder. The upgrade then completed successfully.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** the empty file is not upgraded on moving from v2.8.10 to v3.0.2 (it remains 0 bytes). This plugin used to be a standard part of the install, but now no plugins are included. In my case it turned out the client didn't use this plugin anyway so there was no further issue. YMMV.